# Eclipse for Java not loading in packages and classes

Tags: java, eclipse, package-explorer

so I'm relatively new to Eclipse and programming in general, started using Eclipse for Java a few days ago. It all went well until today. When I open Eclipse, select path, etc. there are no errors or anything but all my classes and packages that are supposed to show on the left side are gone, and it's not the bar that's gone - it's still there, it's just blank. By now I've done some googling but I still have no clue how to fix it. Sure, dragging every file into Eclipse one by one works but even after that, the package explorer bar is still empty as my tea cup right now..

Comment: Could you please attach some screenshot ?)

Comment: Did you accidentally switch to a blank workspace?

Comment: To be honest I have no idea waht I did ergonaut.
Ivan, the project explorer is just empty. Blanko.

Comment: in what perspective are you working ? Window->Open Perspective->Java, then Window->Reset Perspective

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below setting to get the packages/classes back again:

**Window->Reset Perspective**

Answer (score 0):

I think you are accessing wrong workspace.. Switch to correct path.
In eclipse,
**File. -> Switch Workspace -> Other -> select dropdown** too see any other workspace available..
Select correct workspace and check whether the packages and classes are available..